# Find the subspace of Soregenfrey plane that contains no countable dense set

Tags: general-topology

Let [Sorgenfrey Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) be denoted as $\mathbb{R}_{S}^2$ is the cartesian product of two Soregenfrey lines

I am given a task:

> Find a subspace of the Soregenfrey plane that contains no countable
> dense set

I am at loss here as to how to proceed with this question.

I know that the $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is definitely countable and dense, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense in the line

Is there some intuitive way to see that such a set may exist in $\mathbb{R}_S^2$ but not $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @ErickWong Sorry I was thinking of a diagonal line in the plane consisting of $\mathbb{Q} \cap$ Diagonal, I have edited

Comment: The wiki page you linked to mentions the anti-diagonal $\{ (x,-x) : x \in \mathbb R\}$ as an interesting subspace of the Sorgenfrey plane (it's also a subspace in the vector space sense).  Have you considered starting from there?

Comment: @ErickWong Do you know how this result was arrived? Is there a natural way to find this subspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Erick Wong in the comments, consider the anti-diagonal $D:=\{(x,-x)\ |\ x \in \Bbb{R}\}.$ $D$ has no countable dense subspace, since it's an uncountable discrete space.

To see this, note that a particular basic open set containing a point $(x,-x) \in D$ is of the form $D\cap \left([x,x+1)\times [-x,-x+1)\right)=\{(x,-x)\}$, hence $D$ is discrete.

Comment: Why wouldn't $D_Q = \{(x, -x) | x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ be a countable dense set in the subspace? Is it because since singletons are open in the subspace, therefore the points in $D_{R\backslash Q} = \{(x, -x) | x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\}$ is an open set in $D$ that does not contain any element in $D_Q$?

Comment: Also did you mean t write $D \cap ([x, x+1) \times [x, x+2))$?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou Think about what a sequence of rationals $q_n \to x$ looks like.  Does $-q_n \to -x$?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou Yes, sorry there was actually another typo as well. Remember that in discrete spaces all convergent sequences must be eventually constant.